# Count leading tabs in Swift string

Tags: swift, regex

I need to count the number of leading tabs in a Swift string. I know there are fairly simple solutions (e.g. looping over the string until a non-tab character is encountered) but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

I have attempted to use a regex such as `^\\t*` along with the `.numberOfMatches` method but this detects all the tab characters as one match. For example, if the string has three leading tabs then that method just returns `1`. Is there a way to write a regex that treats each individual tab character as a single match?

Also open to other ways of approaching this without using a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\G\t
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vr2rJh/1).

Here,

- `\G` - matches a string start position or end of the previous match position, and
- `\t` - matches a single tab.

Swift test:

```
let string = "\t\t123"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\G\t", options: [])
let numberOfOccurrences = regex.numberOfMatches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
print(numberOfOccurrences) // => 2
```

Comment: Wow, that was shockingly easy. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-regex solution

```
let count = someString.prefix(while: {$0 == "\t"}).count
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution!